How to implement MouseListener, MouseMotionListener,and KeyListener , all in the same program?
I have the following java program that responds to mouse clicks  and mouse movements. It is  working as I wanted. The code appears below.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Z_MouseAndMotionListener extends JPanel  {
  public Z_MouseAndMotionListener() {
     Mouse m = new Mouse();
     addMouseListener(m);
     addMouseMotionListener(m);
  }
  class Mouse implements  MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Pressed");
 }
 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Moved");
 }
 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setSize(500, 500);
 frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setContentPane(new Z_MouseAndMotionListener());
 frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 } 

Now I want to implement keyListener also in the same program.
For that I used the following program(a slightly modified version of the earlier program
displayed above.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Z_MouseAndMotionListener1 extends JPanel {
public Z_MouseAndMotionListener1() {
 Mouse m = new Mouse();
 addMouseListener(m);
 addMouseMotionListener(m);
 }
 class Mouse implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Pressed");
 }
 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Moved");       
 }
 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
 }
 public class KeyEvents extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
 //addKeyListener;

 @override
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
 } 
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setSize(500, 500);
 frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setContentPane(new Z_MouseAndMotionListener1());
 frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 }

 when I try to compile,Iget the error message "Z_MouseAndMotionListener1.java:22: error:      
 Z_MouseAndMotionListener1.KeyEvents is not abstract and does not override abstract method 
  keyReleased(KeyEvent) in KeyListener
 public class KeyEvents extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
      ^"

 Can someone please help me in implementing mouse and key Listeners?


Is there an error or problem occurring with the modified code? Did it work before the modifications? What are the symptoms?

Yes it did work before modification(shown in the 1st program above. The modification was adding the code block -   @override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
}   where I get the error message "Z_MouseAndMotionListener1.java:22: error:
Z_MouseAndMotionListener1.KeyEvents is not abstract and does not override abstract method
keyReleased(KeyEvent) in KeyListener
public class KeyEvents extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
